# Why doesn't xjc generate a List property when maxOccurs isn't specified on an element?

Tags: jaxb

I have a schema that contains sequence with no occurrence defined like the following

```xml
    <complexType name="CultureInfo">
      <sequence>
        <element name="A" type="string"/>
        <element name="B" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
```

After running xjc, JAXB doesn't generate A and B as List<> meaning only one instance always. 
I know I can fix this problem by adding

```xml
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Unfortunately, I can't change the schema. I am wondering and getting some conflicting information, by default meaning if no maxOccurs specified, can A and/or B appear multiple times? Some site says yes, some says no, JAXB says no (that's why no List<>).

Answer (score 1):

When `maxOccurs` is not specified, the default is `1` In XML Schema.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/ section **2.2.1 Occurrence Constraints**:

> The comment element is optional within PurchaseOrderType because the
>   value of the minOccurs attribute in its declaration is 0. In general,
>   an element is required to appear when the value of minOccurs is 1 or
>   more. The maximum number of times an element may appear is determined
>   by the value of a maxOccurs attribute in its declaration. This value
>   may be a positive integer such as 41, or the term unbounded to
>   indicate there is no maximum number of occurrences. The default value
>   for both the minOccurs and the maxOccurs attributes is 1. Thus, when
>   an element such as comment is declared without a maxOccurs attribute,
>   the element may not occur more than once. Be sure that if you specify
>   a value for only the minOccurs attribute, it is less than or equal to
>   the default value of maxOccurs, i.e. it is 0 or 1. Similarly, if you
>   specify a value for only the maxOccurs attribute, it must be greater
>   than or equal to the default value of minOccurs, i.e. 1 or more. If
>   both attributes are omitted, the element must appear exactly once.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I also found the same answer from   http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp